# Почему происходит ошибка компилятора?

Tags: c++

Вылазит `MSB6006    " read access violation. **IsRegistered** was nullptr` VS 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

bool* CheckRegistration(int RegNumber)
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int RegNumber = 0;
    bool* IsRegistered = new bool;
    *IsRegistered = false;

    if (*IsRegistered) {
        int is_Reg = 1; //registered
    }
    else {
        IsRegistered = CheckRegistration(RegNumber);
        //exit(0);
    }
    if (*IsRegistered) {
        int is_Reg = 1; //registered
    }
    else {
        //exit(0);
    }

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: Функция CheckRegistration возвращает указатель, но вы возвращаете false (у которого тип - bool, а не bool*). Как написать это с использованием указателей, я показал во втором примере в своём ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

//почему указатель?
bool CheckRegistration(int RegNumber)
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int RegNumber = 0; //!!! переменные надо инициализировать
    bool IsRegistered = false;

    if (!IsRegistered) {//тут вообще было взятие адреса у указателя
        IsRegistered = CheckRegistration(RegNumber);
    }
    else {
        //exit(0);
    }

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    //память кстати не почистили. new bool сделали, а delete нет

}
```

С указателями у Вас явно не всё в порядке.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
void CheckRegistration(int RegNumber, bool* b)
{
    *b = false;
}

int main()
{
    int RegNumber = 0; //!!! переменные надо инициализировать
    bool* IsRegistered = new bool;
    *IsRegistered = true;
    CheckRegistration(RegNumber, IsRegistered);
    if (!(*IsRegistered)) {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
    delete IsRegistered;
}
```

Comment: под bool надо динамически выделять память

Comment: А, да? А почему?

Comment: чтобы реверсер не узнал результат проверки CheckRegistration

Comment: с взятием адреса протупил

Comment: Я понял. Ладно. Как скажете

Comment: как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Во первых, я не знаю что такое реверсер. Во вторых, если бинарник на выходе не обфусцировать/зашифровать, то запустив его в каком-нибудь IdaPRO или как-там отладчик назывался всё можно вытащить. Не зависимо от того где там у вас данные - на стеке или в куче.

Comment: взломщик, грубо говоря

Comment: ошибка была в инициализации переменной

Comment: @MatthewHaig добавил пример на указателях.

Comment: обнови страницу, теперь другая ошибка, говорил мол нет доступа к памяти

Comment: это тот случай, где вообше не имеет смысль знать адреса(работать с указательями)

Answer (score 0):

Результат функции должен зависить от аргумента, поэтому лучше, например так:

```
bool CheckRegistration(int RegNumber)
{
    return RegNumber % 2; //использовать все аргументы
}
//читайте выше мой комментарий    
int main()
{
    int RegNumber = 0;//!!! обьекты надо инициализировать             
    if (!CheckRegistration(RegNumber)) 
       std::cout << "Hello World!\n";    
    //избавимся от лишных строк
}
```

p.s. C++ это язык для  обьектно ориентированного программирования, поэтому имейте привычку видеть обьекты, а не переменные